# inequality involving successive maxima in sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

In this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.0447, the authors state the following inequality:

For any sequence of real numbers $s_0, s_1, \dots, s_n$ with $\bar{s}_i = \max(s_0, \dots, s_i)$ it holds that 
$$\bar{s}_n^2 + 4 \left [ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \bar{s_i}(s_{i+1}-s_{i}) \right ] \leq 4 s_n^2.$$

The proof is not given, but they say that it suffices to rearrange and complete squares. I did not manage to prove it, and am not even sure what kind of more basic inequality it might follow from. Does someone have an idea?

Comment: Note that the numbers actually start from $0$: $s_0, s_1, \ldots, s_n$. Also, the number on the right side is $4s_n^2$, not $4s_n^4$. Take everything to the right side and try completing the square in $s_n$, then complete the square of the non-perfect square term in $\bar{s}_{n-1}$ and see if you can find a pattern.

Comment: Sorry for all these typos! Thanks, I'll try that.